# tensorflow Dataset shuffle behavior on Iterator reset

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I find `reshuffle_each_iteration` parameter to `tf.Dataset.shuffle` a bit confusing. Consider this code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

flist = ["trimg1", "trimg2", "trimg3", "trimg4"]

filenames = tf.constant(flist)

train_x_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((filenames))
train_x_dataset = train_x_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=10, reshuffle_each_iteration=False)

it_train_x = train_x_dataset.make_initializable_iterator()

next_sample = it_train_x.get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    for epoch in range(3):
        sess.run(it_train_x.initializer)
        print("Starting epoch ", epoch)
        while True:
            try:
                s = sess.run(next_sample)
                print("Sample: ", s)
            except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
                break
```

The code outputs:

```
Starting epoch  0
Sample:  b'trimg2'
Sample:  b'trimg1'
Sample:  b'trimg3'
Sample:  b'trimg4'
Starting epoch  1
Sample:  b'trimg4'
Sample:  b'trimg3'
Sample:  b'trimg2'
Sample:  b'trimg1'
Starting epoch  2
Sample:  b'trimg3'
Sample:  b'trimg2'
Sample:  b'trimg4'
Sample:  b'trimg1'
```

Even though `reshuffle_each_iteration` is `False`, tensorflow still reshuffles dataset after it is iterated over. Is there another way to reset iterator? What's the expected behavior of `reshuffle_each_iteration`?

I know I can fix the `seed` and get the same order each time, the question is about how `reshuffle_each_iteration` is supposed to work.

I'm also aware that more idiomatic way to do epochs is to use `repeat()`, but in my case the actual count of samples will be different for each epoch.

Answer (score 8):

I suspect TensorFlow still reshuffles the dataset at every iteration of your for loop because the iterator is being initialized at each iteration. Every time the iterator is initialized, the shuffle function is applied to the dataset.

The expected behavior is that the iterator is initialized once, and `reshuffle_each_iteration` allows you to choose whether to reshuffle at repeats of the data (every time the original data has been iterated over).

I am not sure how to reformulate your code to deal with the variable number of samples, but here is your code modified using the `repeat()` function to demonstrate my claim:

```
flist = ["trimg1", "trimg2", "trimg3", "trimg4"]

filenames = tf.constant(flist)

train_x_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((filenames))
train_x_dataset = train_x_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=10, reshuffle_each_iteration=False)
train_x_dataset = train_x_dataset.repeat(4)

it_train_x = train_x_dataset.make_initializable_iterator()

next_sample = it_train_x.get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(it_train_x.initializer)
    while True:
        try:
            s = sess.run(next_sample)
            print("Sample: ", s)
        except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
            break
```

Output:

```
Sample:  trimg1
Sample:  trimg2
Sample:  trimg4
Sample:  trimg3
Sample:  trimg1
Sample:  trimg2
Sample:  trimg4
Sample:  trimg3
Sample:  trimg1
Sample:  trimg2
Sample:  trimg4
Sample:  trimg3
Sample:  trimg1
Sample:  trimg2
Sample:  trimg4
Sample:  trimg3
```

Whereas if I set `reshuffle_each_iteration=True`, I get:

```
Sample:  trimg3
Sample:  trimg1
Sample:  trimg2
Sample:  trimg4
Sample:  trimg3
Sample:  trimg2
Sample:  trimg1
Sample:  trimg4
Sample:  trimg3
Sample:  trimg1
Sample:  trimg2
Sample:  trimg4
Sample:  trimg4
Sample:  trimg1
Sample:  trimg2
Sample:  trimg3
```

Hope this helps!

Edit: Further evidence for my claim: these [two test functions](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/4806cb0646bd21f713722bd97c0d0262c575f7e0/tensorflow/python/data/kernel_tests/shuffle_dataset_op_test.py#L151) in the TensorFlow codebase. In this case, a one shot iterator is used, and so it is only initialized once. A batch size of 10 is used on data of size 10, and so each call of `iterator.get_next()` goes over the entire source data. The code checks if each successive call of that function returns the same (shuffled) array.

This discussion on [this issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/15448) might shed some more light on the intended use and expected behavior of the different iterators and perhaps help you figure out a solution to your specific problem.